# identifier not declared 'TDSServerModule' XE7

Tags: delphi

this is  my code for server module for datasnap

```
unit ServerMethodsUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSAuth;

type
  TDSServerModule1 = class(TDSServerModule)
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

but the IDE of DELPHI XE7 say 'undeclared identifier TDSServerModule'

Comment: Whenever you are faced with a similar message take these two simple steps: 1) activate help and the index tab on the left 2) type the undeclared identifier in the search box and press Enter. The document on the right side tells you its complete qualified identifier. `TDSServerModule` seems to be declared in Datasnap.DSProviderDataModuleAdapter which is missing from your uses clause.

Comment: Why is it no one can figure out how to use the documentation? Or the source? Search->Find in Files would have located the proper unit as well. When you have an *undeclared identifier* error, it's always one of two things: a typo in your code, or you've not added the proper unit to your uses clause. Documentation or the source can find the proper unit; they can also show you how to spell the identifier correctly if that's the cause of the problem.